# How can I make mice in macOS lefthand by default?

Tags: mac, mouse

I am left-handed and use macOS (MacBook pro 2018) with more than one mouse (home and outwards). I have to always change the primary button when I use the other mouse.

Is there a way to set **all mice that I connect left-handed by default**?

---

MacBook Pro 2018

macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: The answers in the article [Swap Mouse Button using AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89721/swap-mouse-button-using-applescript) might be helpful.